# Is there a membership software that is good for content specific to a single user/member?

Tags: database, file-management, document-management, information-management, crm

I'm looking for something that provides a simple way to upload a file (i.e mp4, pdf, etc.) and assign the file to a specific customer... and then that customer would be provided with login information to then have a place to access that file that is specific to them.

Additionally, it would not just be one file per customer... a customer would have multiple files that are relevant only to them, and so the platform should provide a way for the customer to see and access each file that is assigned to them.

I'm looking for a Cloud service that can manage storing files such as documents, photos, and even video files that might be 3GB or more.

Ideally, there would be a Members area that works as a place for customers to login and access files that are specific to them and NO OTHER customers, but also be able to have it be like a members area that does have shared content with other users, which would serve as like a learning/training center.

I'm familiar with Membership sites that has different levels of access... and this is fine for a training/learning center with like groups of permissions.  The issue is that I also want a simple way to have a place to upload files that are specific to just a single customer and no other customers.  I know this can be done in many existing Membership Platforms, but to do the part of files specific to a single customer is challenging (i.e. I have to setup a page specific for each customer, or a permission level for each customer).

Any recommendations?

Comment: Have you looked into a CMS?

Comment: well... the range of ways to get this done is huge! -- what do you think of cloud-storages like [nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/)? or maybe a ftp-server with password-protected folders is enough?

Comment: Do you want to host it on your own server? Or should it be available as a service? What total file volume do you need? About how many customers? What is your budget?

Comment: Google Drive does all that with shared folders.

Comment: Content for one specific user, some shared (read only i'm guessing) content for groups or all users, assume you may want polls, discussions, etc. also to be group or all user based at some point.  Instead of a cms (content mgmt system) perhaps a lms (learning mgmnt system) would be better?  Most allow user or group of user granular control of content like what you describe... Not a lot of free or Free ones out there though. I'd start wtih looking at the feature set moodle has....

Answer (score 1):

ok... for me it sounds that [nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/) is a kind of software you are looking for:

- simple upload of files and folders via web-interface, WebDAV (local file-browser) or also FTP is possible (with a tiny bit tweaking)
- also syncing via own cross-platform apps (desktop & mobile) can be done
- file size is only limited by server quota (there is a setting for accepted file sizes in the sever-GUI)
- not sure what you mean with "*assign the file to a specific customer*", but also tagging and commenting files is possible
- users can be organized in groups
- files and folders can be shared with multiple groups and users
- automatic notifications and mails (via php or smtp) to users
- every user can access his own/shared files via web-interface, WebDAV (local file-browser) or also use the sync-clients
- seamless download of single files or complete folders (as zip-archive)
- and many more other features...

there is also a [demo](https://demo.nextcloud.com/) you can try out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so lets talk google drive.

You can create a folder on it, right click and share with any other google account simply by typing in their email, clicking view or change, and share.

Free gives you approx 15gb total.  You can pay $9.99 a month or get a discount for paying for the whole year at once and get 1TB of storage.

Signing up for a google account is free, and chances are they probably already have one.